# ArrayAdapter<String> doesn't support getCheckedItemIds()?

Tags: android

I hope to use lv.getCheckedItemIds().length to get the sum of selected items.
It seems that ArrayAdapter doesn't support getCheckedItemIds(), right?

```
private void InitListView(int pos) {
    List<String> msgList = getSMS(pos);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, msgList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter2);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            SetSelectedAndTotal();
        }
    });
}

private void SetSelectedAndTotal(){
    selectedAndTotal.setText(lv.getCheckedItemIds().length+ "/"
            + lv.getCount());       
}


    public List<String> getSMS(int pos) {
        List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse(valueList.get(pos));
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,
                null);

        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
            String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
            sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body);

        }
        return sms;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a snippet from the documentation on using `getCheckedItemIds()`:

> The result is only valid if the choice mode has not been set to CHOICE_MODE_NONE and the adapter has stable IDs. (hasStableIds() == true)

By default, `BaseAdapter` (and it subclass `ArrayAdapter`) do not support stable item ids, so if you want to utilize this you will need to create your own subclass that returns `true` from `hasStableIds()` and always returns a unique value from `getItemId()` for each element.

Otherwise, you'll have to use `getCheckedItemPositions()` instead, which in the use case you described would provide the same answer you need without the extra work.